# Sending Email from .NET using windows live smtp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtpclient, windows-live

I have configured smtp settings in web.config and I was able to successfully send email when working on my local machine. But when I uploaded the code on the server, its giving me following exception

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted

Meanwhile, I also received an email from Microsoft telling me that an attempt to login to my account from a new location was blocked. I clearly understand the problem that server is in a different part of the world than where I usually login to a Windows Live account. That's why it is blocking the account to login. But I want it to login and send email using my credentials on from remote server. There must be some settings in Windows Live account but I failed to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Contacting Hotmail Support Center first to find out if its really possible what you are intending to do might be helpful. I think if hotmail web administration has put a security check, it must be for a purpose of stopping such remote login activities.